# extended initializer list in older versions of C++

Tags: c++, c++11

When compiling, I get a warning:

```
extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Here is the offending code:

```
std::vector<std::string> command_parse(std::string command) {
    std::istringstream iss(command);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}, std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
         std::back_inserter(tokens)); //This line gets the warning

    return tokens;
}
```

Is there a way to make this code compatible with older versions of c++?

Comment: `std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}` -> `std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss)`, the same to the second istream_iterator

Comment: @PiotrS. Thanks! I will accept if you post.

Comment: This is also poor C++11. In C++11, you would say: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}, {}, std::back_inserter(tokens));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use parentheses instead of braces for the initializers.

```
copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
      std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
      std::back_inserter(tokens) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace curly braces with round parentheses:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(tokens));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, use parenthesis rather than curly-braces. The curly-braces denote *uniform-initialization* which was a feature added in C++11.

There is also the option of returning the vector directly, since it takes iterators for its constructor:

```c++
std::vector<std::string> command_parse(std::string command) {
    return std::vector<std::string>(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::istringstream(command) >> std::skipws),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
    );
}
```